# how to automatically update daily datetime in django

Tags: django, django-models, python-datetime, django-database

Hi I want to automatically update datetime daily in my database and put the today date as now then it show the subtract the start day and no and give me the delta is there any way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you use `timezone.now()` ?

Comment: thanks for your answer but does it update my database daily and put the current date in my models? @Utkucan

Comment: Why you need update database ? Could you add some details

Answer (score 0):

With `TIMEZONE` enabled in `settings.py`:

```
from django.utils import timezone

now = timezone.now()
```

And without `TIMEZONE` set:

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
```

And with any of above:

```
from datetime import timedelta

tommorow_with_same_hour = now + timedelta(days=1)
```